# AS3: Descendants with multiples conditions

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, conditional-statements, descendant

Example of my XML list:

```
<listnode>
   <nodeA id="1">
       <nodeB id="1" />
   </nodeA>
   <nodeA id="2">
       <nodeB id="2" />
   </nodeA>
</listnode>

<listnode>
   <nodeA id="2">
       <nodeB id="2" />
   </nodeA>
   <nodeA id="1">
       <nodeB id="3" />
   </nodeA>
   <nodeA id="5">
       <nodeB id="1" />
   </nodeA>
</listnode>

<listnode>
    ... etc
```

I'm trying to get an XML list based on multiple conditions. With one condition, it's fine, using something like:

```
var  list:XMLList = list.(descendants("nodeA").@id.contains("1"));
```

This gives me a list of all the **listnode** in **list** that have any descendant named **nodeA** with an attribute **id=1**.

How can I retrieve the same list, but looking also for the **id** of the **nodeB** nodes? Something like:

```
var  list:XMLList = list.(descendants("nodeA").@id.contains("1") && nodeA.descendants("nodeB").@id.contains("3"));
```

In this example, that should give me a list with one node:

```
<listnode>
   <nodeA id="2">
       <nodeB id="2" />
   </nodeA>
   <nodeA id="1">
       <nodeB id="3" />
   </nodeA>
   <nodeA id="5">
       <nodeB id="1" />
   </nodeA>
</listnode>
```

Because it has a nodeA with id=1 who has a nodeB with id=3.

Any ideas?

Comment: @locrizak: thx for the reply, but I can't see how to exactly apply that to my code. Could you be more specific?

Comment: var  list:XMLList = list..nodeA.(@id == "1")..nodeB.(@id=="3"); If it works I'll explain how its working.

Comment: That gives me a list of nodeB, but what I need is a list of listnode that match those conditions... do you knonw how to get that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED**

```
list.(descendants("nodeA").(@id.contains("1") && descendants("nodeB").@id.contains("3")).length() > 0)
```

What about this?

Comment: @Timofei Davydik: thank you, but with that line of code returns all nodes with any descendants with those attributes, even if the nodeB that has id=3 is not inside a nodeA that has id=1. I want to check for the id=3 of nodeB only inside the nodes nodeA that have id=1, and if both are true, return the listnode that contains that.

Comment: @Albert R Oh, i got it wrong first time, now understand. I'll try to fix it

Comment: @Timofei Davydik: thank you, I would really appreciate that, I've tried many diferent things but none works...

Comment: @Timofei Davydik: it gives me the exact same nodes as your previous answer. It returns nodes that have a descendant nodeB with id=3, even if this nodeB is not insidea a nodeA with id=1...

Comment: @Albert R Are you sure you replaced the code? This gives me only second node for your XML `list.(descendants("nodeA").(@id.contains("1") && descendants("nodeB").@id.contains("3")).length() > 0)`

Comment: @Timofei Davydik: FINALLY!!!! It works now!! I had replaced the code but I had to replace something else that I hadn't. Thank you so much dude!!!! I was getting crazy already with this... I reaaaally appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, conditions can be combined.

```
var list:XML = <list>
<listnode>
   <nodeA id="1">
       <nodeB id="1" />
   </nodeA>
   <nodeA id="2">
       <nodeB id="2" />
   </nodeA>
</listnode>

<listnode>
   <nodeA id="2">
       <nodeB id="2" />
   </nodeA>
   <nodeA id="1">
       <nodeB id="3" />
   </nodeA>
   <nodeA id="5">
       <nodeB id="1" />
   </nodeA>
</listnode>
</list>;
var result:XMLList = list.listnode.descendants("*").(@id=="1" && children().length() > 0);
```

Comment: thx for your reply. The thing is, I can't see in your line of code where you're checking for 2 conditions, I only see one...

Comment: `@id=="1" && children().length() > 0` - this is two conditions, combined by AND. You can use OR, too.

Comment: Thank you alxx, I solved it already thanks to Timofei, but I really appreciate your advice also